# Intersection of binomial random variables

Tags: probability

I'm having trouble with a supposedly easy exercise in elementary probability. We're given that the probability of a boy being left-handed is $0.12$, and $0.08$ for a girl. Then in a group of 25 kids, 10 male and 15 female, the exercise asks me to find the probability of $2$ boys and $1$ girl being left-handed.

I thought the probability would be

$${10 \choose 2}\times0.12^2\times0.88^8\times{15 \choose 1}\times0.08\times0.92^{14}\approx0.0870$$

but the solution my teacher provided us with says

$${10 \choose 2}\times0.12^2\times0.88^8+{15 \choose 1}\times0.08\times0.92^{14}\approx0.6065$$

At first I thought the plus sign was nonsense, but now I'm just confused about this. Surely the probability of **exactly** 2 boys and 1 girl being left-handed in such a large group can't be 60%, I think...

Comment: The **plus sign** is, indeed, nonsense.

Comment: Your solution is correct; the later solution does not have a clear interpretation for me. In general addition of probabilities occurs for unions of events$$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B).$$ So the second equation *would* be correct if $P(A \cap B) = 0$, however in your example about boys/girls this is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

$P(AB) = P(A)\cdot P(B)$ if A and B are independent.  Your A and B (boys being left-handed and girls being left-handed) are independent, so your answer is correct.

One way to think about is that for likely events A and B the adding method could give a probability greater than 1.